# Elasticsearch failed to parse date field format

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I 'm new with ealsticsearch and I use a third party ealsticsearch im trying to make query using spring data it's work with all of string fields but when i try to make query with a timestamps field I get an error  :

this my query :

```
{
...
  "transmissionTime": "2021-09-08 11:53:00.000",
...
}
```

this's my field mapping

```
@JsonFormat(
        shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", locale = "fr_FR")
private Timestamp transmission_date_and_time;
```

when I execute my query i get this error :

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=failed to parse date field [1631098380000] with format [yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ]]
```

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch does not use Jackson annotations (at least not since version 4.0). Which version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Modify your index mapping as

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```